# No puedo arreglar HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis

He intentado todo lo que dicen los foros y no puedo arreglar este error
El servidor web está configurado para no mostrar una lista los contenidos de este directorio.

Activé el directory browsing, agregué el sitio a IIS, pero ejecuto en Visual Studio 2017 el programa y sale el error.

Todo lo que tengo es el web api de un tutorial:

```
 public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[]
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);

            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }

    }

public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

    }

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Product App</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <h2>All Products</h2>
        <ul id="products" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Search by ID</h2>
        <input type="text" id="prodId" size="5" />
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find( );" />
        <p id="product" />
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var uri = 'api/products';

    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Send an AJAX request
      $.getJSON(uri)
          .done(function (data) {
            // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
              // Add a list item for the product.
              $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
            });
          });
    });

    function formatItem(item) {
      return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
    }

    function find( ) {
      var id = $('#prodId').val();
      $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
          .done(function (data) {
            $('#product').text(formatItem(data));
          })
          .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
          });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como ven es un modelo, un controlador y un html que hace una petición ajax.

Mirando las carpetas del pc veo que está iis y otra iis express.

Esto es lo que tengo en iis:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me falta algo por seleccionar?

adfj dfadsklfja dsfkljads klfjdkls fjkldsajflkadsjf lksdjalkf sdklfja
dfadsfadsf
fasdfasdfa